# How to show top of the next card in viewportFraction in pageView?

Tags: flutter, dart

viewport use shows the bottom side of the next card. I want to show the top side and also only one shadow card

**in initState()**

```
controller = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.85);
```

**widget**

```
PageView(
                controller: controller,
                reverse: true,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(...),
                  Container(...),
                  Container(...),
                  Container(...),
                ]),
```

I just wanted to say

[image: I just wanted to say]

Comment: Have you looked at `Stack` ?

Comment: how to stack scroll